# Windows 10 Start Menu Toolbars that I remove, reappear after restarting PC

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I added some custom toolbars to my start menu that lists the contents of specific directories. But they were taking too much room on my start bar so I have removed them several times but every time I restart my computer, they come back to haunt me. Does anybody know how to fix this? It is incredibly annoying and I can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: What custom toolbars? How did you install it?

Comment: I didn't install anything, it is a windows feature that I have been using since Windows 7. You can add a toolbar to the start menu by simply right clicking it hovering over "Toolbars" and selecting "New Toolbar". Then you just choose a directory and it adds it to the start bar.

Comment: I just noticed it also is not saving the position I have it docked at. I usually have it docked on the right side of my monitors but I just moved it down to the bottom where most people have it and after I restarted it was back on the right side again.

When I did that I also unchecked "Show Cortona button" & "Show Task View button" as well as hid the search button and all of that was saved after the restart.I should note that all changes I make to the tiles that appear after clicking the windows button, they are also being saved after restart.

So it seems to just be toolbars & position.

Comment: Stuff I pin to the start bar also saves. I'm sure this can be fixed through the Registry Editor but I have no idea what I am looking for. Does anybody know the path to something I should try renaming in the Registry editor that might control the toolbars and the position of the start bar?

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to come up with the right search query on Google and found the solution to this issue! It was a simple Registry Editor fix like I expected, here are the details...

> 1. Type regedit in RUN dialog box and press Enter. It'll open Registry Editor.
> 2. Now check for a DWORD "NoSaveSettings" in right-side pane under following keys:
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
>   HKEY_USERS.Default\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
>   HKEY_USERS.Default\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Program Manager\Restrictions

More info at https://www.askvg.com/solution-windows-desktop-does-not-save-user-customized-settings/

I hope this help someone else that might be having the same issue.

Cheers!